# What is the formal definition of cardinality of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know the intuition behind the concept of cardinality (the number of elements of a given set) and the formal definition of sets with equal cardinalities, but what's the formal definition of the cardinality of sets itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Formally, we can define cardinality in the following way.
A bijection $f:E\to F$ is a function from $E$ to $F$ which is both surjective and injective. We say that two sets are equivalent if there exists a bijection between them. Finally, a cardinality can be defined as an equivalence class for this equivalence relation. This means the cardinal $3$ will be the class of all sets of size $3$ (any two of these sets are in bijection with each other). Similarly, the cardinal $\aleph_0$ is the class containing the sets $\mathbb N, \mathbb N^2,\mathbb Q, \mathbb Z,\dots$

Comment: Do you know any books where I can find this definition?

Comment: For instance the wikipedia page on cardinality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality uses this definition and references some books.

Comment: But we can't see the cardinality as a equivalence relation because it concerns _all_ sets.

Comment: As it is written on wikipedia: "this is an equivalence relation on the class of all sets". Notice that they don't write "the set of all sets", since there is no set of all sets, but indeed they form a class (a more general notion). Even the equivalence class formed by the sets of cardinality $\aleph_0$ is not a set: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271187/is-it-possible-to-make-the-set-of-all-sets-of-cardinality-aleph-0

Answer (score 1):

The cardinality of $A$ is the equivalence class of $A$ under the equivalence relation "equal cardinalities" (the existence of bijections).

Since in most cases this equivalence class is a proper class, we often identify it with a particular representative when we can. For example, finite ordinals or $\aleph$ numbers.

To see why this makes sense, we return to the finite case, where in our language and intuition we don't separate the notions of "cardinal" from "cardinality". That is, $5$ is the cardinality of fingers I have attached to my left hand, but it's also the cardinal number of the fingers I have attached to my left hand.

Comment: Do you know any books where I can find this definition?

Comment: But we can't see the cardinality as a equivalence relation because it concerns _all_ sets.

Comment: We can define the notion of equivalence relation in the meta-theory, that is, using classes. This is a "class equivalence relation". Namely, we can define a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ which is true if and only if $x$ and $y$ have the same cardinality. Then the equivalence classes are defined uniformly with $\varphi$ when we fix $y$ as parameter (that is, the equivalence class of $\Bbb N$ is $\{x\mid\varphi(x,\Bbb N)\}$.

Comment: In Jech's **Set Theory** he defines "cardinality" as cardinal numbers to begin with, by the way.

Comment: Wait, I don't get something. I thought cardinality of a set is suppose to be "some kind" of number but you define it as a set (I mean, since equivalence class is a set). How does that work? $|\{5,8,11\}|=3$ but $3$ alone, isn't a set now is it? Can you walk me through the idea?

Comment: @William: **Everything** is a set. We identify the natural numbers with the finite von Neumann ordinals, so $0$ is $\varnothing$, and $n+1=n\cup\{n\}$, so $1=\{0\}=\{\varnothing\}$ and $2=\{0,1\}=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ and $3=\{0,1,2\}$ and so on.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I looked up and read about ordinals and the Von Neumann ordinals now and I think I may still not have a clear picture about cardinalities. You see, I was looking for a solid definition of cardinality of a set because my college textbook defines it as "measure of number of elements" of a set. I'm not happy with that definition since "the number of elements" part is meaningless when the set is infinite (at least to me, what do you think about that definition?).

Comment: @AsafKaragila So anyway I'm looking for a nice definition that is not too advanced either since I have only a small section on cardinalities to cover in my course. Any suggestions?

Comment: @William: The point is that there is a *canonical* representative for each (well-orderable) cardinality. Namely, we can point out at a particular set of a given cardinality. So we can identify the number $3$ with that particular set. As for the meaninglessness of "number of elements", it's not meaningless, it's still "the number of elements", it just becomes *more apparent* how sets are more fundamental than numbers when you consider it that way.