# Set of Infinite Sets Contradiction?

Tags: logic, set-theory, paradoxes

Consider the set $S$ that contains all sets $X$ such that $|X|\geq |\Bbb N|$.

The whole *reason* ZFC was made was because of Russel’s paradox right? And so we know that we can't have a set that contains itself. So because of this: $S \notin S$

And so we have that $|S| < |\Bbb N|$.(i.e: that there are only finitely many sets of infinite cardinality).

But *clearly* this is not the case! One way to see this is to note that all of:

$\{x \in \Bbb{Z}$ $s.t. x \equiv 1$ (mod 2)}, $\{x \in \Bbb{Z}$ $s.t. x \equiv 1$ (mod 3)}, $\{x \in \Bbb{Z}$ $s.t. x \equiv 1$ (mod 4)}, ... $\in S$

So clearly $|S| \geq |\Bbb N|$

This brings about a contradiction. And one would determine that it was irrational to consider the set $S$.

My question, essentially, is: What's going on here? Surely there is some problem with the logic above, as it should be rational to consider the collection of sets with infinite cardinality, right?

I'm afraid my ZFC knowledge isn't quite up to par (at all) so I'm not able to work out exactly what is wrong with my argument.

In my search for answers I came across some other posts on here, but none of them seemed to be directly comparable to my question.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: The closest related post that I was able to find was this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271187/is-it-possible-to-make-the-set-of-all-sets-of-cardinality-aleph-0 but I'm not sure that the distinction between > and >= is completely irrelevant. As well, it hasn't particularly cleared up for me _why_ we can't consider this set S, as it seems intuitive to be able to do so.

Comment: Why is your set $S$ any more "rational" than the Russell set $\{x:x\not\in x\}$?  Also, Russell's paradox has absolutely nothing to do with whether it is possible for a set to be an element of itself.

Comment: There is no problem: you have simply proved that the set of all infinite sets does not exist.

Comment: @Jack "it seems intuitive to be able to do so" Why? The onus is on the proof-writer to justify each step. It's not enough to just say "it seems intuitive," you have to provide an argument within the theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself. And there isn't one. (And indeed when first starting out it can be a bit tricky to see how to use the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms to justify the existence of "obvious" sets, but this gets better with practice.)

Comment: Are you aware that there are set theories which do not have Russell’s Paradox problems, but you still have sets $A$ such that $A\in A$? E.g.,  [Aczel’s Anti-Foundation Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel's_anti-foundation_axiom?wprov=sfti1). Russell’s paradox doesn’t arise because of sets that contain themselves, it arises from unrestricted comprehension (thinking that just because you can describe what you want the elements of the set to be, that creates a set). This is exactly your problem here: you have to justify tha t$S$ is a set, and you are not doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you define $S$ to be the "set" of $X$ that satisfy some property. If you do not tell where you pick $X$ from, the object $S$ you're creating might not even be a set. Some of the sets that are constructed this way and is axiomatized to be a set are the power set $P(A)=\{X\mid X\subseteq A\}$, and the union $\bigcup C=\{x\mid \exists A\in C : x\in A\}$. If $S$ is not a set, some properties we are familiar with might not be true.

See the term "class" for further information.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it: Essentially I was naively considering the 'collection', S, of infinite cardinality sets to be a set? When in fact, while we can "rationally consider" the *collection* S; we can not view it as a set. Is this more correct?

Comment: exactly. See the term “class” for more specific detail of the “collections” you meant.